# How to avoid table scan on SQL Server in this situation

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, query-performance, full-table-scan

There are two tables, `Costs` and `Logs`. The data in `Costs` table can be in the millions of rows, and in `Logs` table it can be billions of rows.

I need to update the `CostBy` column in `Costs` table in a service task in production environment within 100 records each run.

```
CREATE TABLE Cost
(
    C_PK uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
    C_CostBy varchar(3) not null
)

CREATE TABLE Logs
(
    L_PK uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
    L_ParentTable varchar(255) not null,  -- Table Cost and other table's name
    L_ParentID uniqueidentifier not null, -- Cost's pk and other table's pk
    L_Event varchar(3) not null, -- Part are 'ADD' and other event types
    L_User varchar(3) not null 
 )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [L_ParentID] 
    ON [dbo].[Costs] ([L_ParentID] ASC)
```

Here is the original update statement:

```
UPDATE TOP(100) Costs
SET CostBy = ISNULL(L_User, '~UK')
FROM Costs
LEFT JOIN Logs ON L_ParentID = C_PK AND L_Event = 'ADD'
WHERE CostBy = ''
```

However, the statement introducing a massive performance issue, high cost of table scan in `Costs` table.

My question is how to avoid the table scan in `Costs` table or how to optimize the update statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your displayed T-SQL does not compile, please post the correct code. Also, a few rows of sample data would be nice.

Comment: What's the reason for updating just the top 100 rows?  Is that a functional requirement, or are you doing this to update a few results at a time / making multiple calls?

Comment: Is this a one off task, or will this code be used on a regular basis (i.e. is there a requirement to update the Costs table every 10 minutes / every time someone performs some action  / etc, or is this just correcting some invalid data in an ad-hoc task?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following.

First, create an index on Logs, including all the relevant columns:

```
CREATE INDEX ix ON Logs 
(
  L_Parent_ID -- join condition, variable
)
INCLUDE 
(
  L_User -- no filter condition, but you use it your update
)
WHERE 
(
  L_Event = 'ADD' -- join condition, constant
)
```

If this is a unique index, ie. only a single row will ever exist with ADD event for a given parent ID, make sure to make this a unique index as it can dramatically improve performance.

Second, and this is a hit and miss situation, you may try with an index on Costs (CostBy) because you're only looking for empty CostBy values to update. This index will need to be updated upon your query because it's updating it, so it may slow down your query instead of speeding it up. It depends on a number of factors.

If you have an enterprise license, try both with with `WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)`, it can significantly improve IO time at the expense of CPU. It depends which is your bottleneck.

Additionally, depending on the nature of your data, updating statistics may improve your queries. If there is a disproportionate number of rows with CostBy = '' to other values in there, you may benefit from full statistics on that field. Consider `NORECOMPUTE` if you only need them for this specific query, this one time.

```
CREATE STATISTICS st_Costs_CostBy
ON Costs (CostBy)  
WITH FULLSCAN, NORECOMPUTE;
```